# Photo slideshow program with location information

Tags: photography, maps, slideshow

I'm trying to create a photo **slideshow** of my last travel, and I'd like to show on a **map** where I were. Ideally, by displaying a minimap on each photo of their geolocation (it's in the exif metadata), or by displaying the full map before each group of photos that are roughly taken at the same place.

I've found numerous possibilities to create the photo slideshow, but I've not found any solution to automate the map generation. I'd gladly take any proposition that could bring me closer to a nice slideshow.

At that point, I don't really care about the required OS, online or offline, free or paid, generating a video or not.

Thanks!